Laravel Many-To-Many Relationship working and fetching correct data, but shows "null" on access
in my Laravel application, I have many to many relationships with 2 tables, ls_blogs & ls_blog_categories, with the ls_blog_category_ls_blog table as a pivot, here is the code for better context
ls_blogs  migration:
Schema::create('ls_blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
 ..Other fields.

ls_blog_categories migration:
if (!Schema::hasTable('ls_blog_categories')) {
            Schema::create('ls_blog_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->boolean('active')->default(false);
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

Pivot
  Schema::create('ls_blog_category_ls_blog', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('ls_blog_id')->nullable()->constrained()->nullOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('ls_blog_category_id')->nullable()->constrained()->nullOnDelete();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

LsBlog Model:
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(LsBlogCategory::class, 'ls_blog_category_ls_blog', 'ls_blog_id', 'ls_blog_category_id')
            ->wherePivotNotNull('ls_blog_category_id')
            ->where('ls_blog_categories.active', true);
    }

LsBlogCategory Model
   public function blogs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(LsBlog::class, 'ls_blog_category_ls_blog')
            ->wherePivotNotNull('ls_blog_id')
            ->where('ls_blogs.is_active', true);
    }

Livewire Component trying to access
    public function mount($id)
    {
        $this->blog = LsBlog::with('categories')->find($id);
        dd($this->blog, $this->blog->categories); 

Result:


Try with this  i fix it with adding the layout attribut to the Livewire component and it works fine  :
LsBlog Model :
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LsBlog extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['title'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(LsBlogCategory::class,'ls_blog_category_ls_blog');
    }
}

LsBlogCategory Model :
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LsBlogCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'active'];

    public function blogs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(LsBlog::class, 'ls_blog_category_ls_blog');
    }
}

lsblogs migration :
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('ls_blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('ls_blogs');
    }
};

ls_blog_categories Migration :
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('ls_blog_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->boolean('active')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('ls_blog_categories');
    }
};

ls_blog_category_ls_blog Migration :
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('ls_blog_category_ls_blog', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('ls_blog_category_id')->constrained('ls_blog_categories');
            $table->foreignId('ls_blog_id')->constrained('ls_blogs');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('ls_blog_category_ls_blog');
    }
};

Livewire Component :
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\LsBlog;
use Livewire\Attributes\Layout;

#[Layout('layouts.app')]
class BlogShow extends Component
{
    public $blog;

    public function mount($id)
    {
        $this->blog = LsBlog::with('categories')->findOrFail($id);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.blog-show');
    }
}

Livewire view :
<div class="container">
    @if ($blog)
        <h1>{{ $blog->title }}</h1>

        <h3>Categories:</h3>
        <ul>
            @forelse ($blog->categories as $category)
                <li>
                    {{ $category->name }}
                    <br> Created At: {{ $category->pivot->created_at }}
                    <br> Updated At: {{ $category->pivot->updated_at }}
                </li>
            @empty
                <li>No categories available.</li>
            @endforelse
        </ul>
    @else
        <p>Blog not found.</p>
    @endif
</div>

layout :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Application</title>

    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    {{ $slot }}

    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>

